# Download multiple files from gridview from download button

Tags: asp.net, database, c#-4.0, gridview, zip

I am saving the path of the file in database and file is in server folder and the gridview control is used to show the files from the database. i need to download the selective files from the gridview using download button Click event.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btn_download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
            zip.AddDirectoryByName("records");
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if ((row.FindControl("chkSelectoptn") as CheckBox).Checked)
                {
                    string filePath = (row.FindControl("lblFilePath") as Label).Text;
                    zip.AddFile(filePath, "records");
                }
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.BufferOutput = true;
            string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

I am using a label **lblFilePath** to give the path of the file name which we had store in the database.

But **"FileNotFoundException"** occurs.

Please suggest.

Comment: `zip.AddFile` requires physical path on the server. Several issues may result in the error. 1) `filePath` is path relative to web root. Use `Server.MapPath` to resolve physical path. 2) The account which runs Web server doesn't have permission to the path.

Comment: Problem Solved !!!